# Google Closure Compiler, how to handle JSC_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY gracefully?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm using a design pattern that uses the return statement to expose public class methods.

Problem is: I'm getting a **lot** of `JSC_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY` warnings in Closure Compiler's Advanced mode, which makes it difficult to check the warnings that actually matter.

Example of the pattern I use:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

/**
 * @constructor
 */
var MyClass = function() {

    var someFunc = function(myString) {
        console.log(myString);
    }

    return {
        myPublicFunc: someFunc
    };
}

var myClassInstance = new MyClass();
myClassInstance.myPublicFunc('Hello World');
```

Warnings:

```
JSC_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY: Property myPublicFunc never defined on MyClass \
    at line 16 character 0
myClassInstance.myPublicFunc('Hello World');
```

Output (formatted):

```
(new function() {
    return {
        a: function(a) {
            console.log(a)
        }
    }
}).a("Hello World");
```

Which is weird, because Closure understood what the code was doing and compiled the code correctly, renaming `myPublicFunc` consistently to `a`. So why did I get this warning? Am I doing something wrong?

Note: I do not want to turn off these warnings because it would also hide warnings I actually care about. I also do not want to use quoted strings or exports because I do want Closure to compress these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is annotated incorrectly. It's actually not a constructor and in this case the `new` keyword is unnecessary. Your function simply returns an anonymous type with a `myPublicFunc` property.

To annotate such a pattern, you would use the record type:

```
/** @return {{myPublicFunc: function(string) }} */
var MyClass = function() {

    var someFunc = function(myString) {
        console.log(myString);
    }

    return {
        myPublicFunc: someFunc
    };
};

var myClassInstance = MyClass(); // new keyword not needed
myClassInstance.myPublicFunc('Hello World');
```

Another annotation option is to create an interface and type-cast the returned object to be that interface. This option would be useful when multiple functions return an object that conforms to the same interface.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

```
/** @type {function(new:{myPublicFunc: function(string)} )} */
var MyClass = function() {...
```

The function can be called with "new" but doesn't return an instance of "MyClass".

Comment: Using the new annotation with the record type generates a "Bad type annotation" error when I test it.

Comment: that is unfortunate, we should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
MyClass.prototype.myPublicFunc = null;
```

would solve the problem though I don't know whether this is the best solution.

I don't really know how the compiler works, but I could imagine that if you have a constructor function, it expects instance properties to be assigned to `this` inside the constructor or to `MyClass.prototype`.

If you remove the `@constructor` annotation and omit `new`, then there is not warning (but the compiled code is only `console.log("Hello World");`.