# Javascript obfuscator / minifier for projects using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, obfuscation, minify

what is the best JS minifier / obfuscator to use for projects that use JQuery? I'm currently using the closure compiler and I've also tried YUI but they never seem to minify and optimise my function names or variable names, effectively all they do is remove whitespace and comments whereas I'm trying to make my code as small as possible and hide as much as possible.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Just Google and try different ones.  There's several online ones that I've used before, but I can't give you the URLs because I don't have them.  I just search when I need one.  Try doing the same :)

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript , it seems you already have the best tools for the purpose... by the way, you can always use one of the web obfuscator that google can provide you (like i did at the time)

Comment: I wouldn't be using function or variable name optimisations unless you have unit tests written.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) again.
It has 3 execution levels

1. **Whitespace only**  You used this setting. Just redundant whitespaces are removed.
2. **Simple** In addition to removing whitespaces this renames your variables and function names to shorten the overall scripts, but leave your code intact.
3. **Advanced** This further improves the *simple*  setting by possible restructuring your code. So, e.g., some functions may get inlined etc.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have tried this before but I get warnings on the advanced mode for things like this : JSC_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY: Property done never defined on ? at line 611 character 0
$.getScript

Comment: @user1548054 [Here](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/error-ref?hl=de) is the documentation of errors. Like any other advanced code manipulation, closure compiler has some restrictions to the way you should code.

Comment: hah what a surprise, the warning I get isn't even mentioned :(

Comment: @user1548054 Maybe you should have a look [at this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11178589/1169798).

Answer (score 0):

Closure is a good minifier. Also there are other minifiers worth to check,

Packer: http://dean.edwards.name/packer/

JSMin: http://crockford.com/javascript/jsmin

Comment: Thanks, JSMin is dated 2003, and packer is dated 2004 are they compatible with JQuery?

Comment: this post by the originator of jQuery may lead you away from packer  http://ejohn.org/blog/library-loading-speed/ Essentially The time to uncompress defeats the packing

Comment: also caching packed files is an issue